# Aligning full width fixed header with main content?

Tags: html, css

First question so sorry if this is a bit squiffy.

I'm trying to get a full (100%) width fixed header with content within, such as logo and navigation links, that is aligned to the main container. I'd like to do this without the use of margining left or right on the logo/nav content as that doesn't seem particularly flexible.

I tried putting the header div within the container block, that fixes the alignment issue but then I can no longer go full width.

So basically how do I get content in a full width fixed header to align with content in the main content of the page?

Here is my html (sorry if its messy, I've only been at this a week or so):

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my CSS, I left the logo image out and in place is just a beige block:

```
body {
margin: 0px;
background-color: darkgray;
}

#header{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
background-image: url("images/bg-header.jpg");
opacity: 0.9;
}

#logo {
height: 100%;
width: 300px;
background-color: beige;
}

#container {
width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
height: 1000px;
background-color:gray;
}

#footer{
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background-image: url("images/bg-header.jpg");
}
```

Any advice?

Thank-you

Comment: Holy sweet mother of.. I was NOT expecting such an instantaneous and flourishing response! THANK-YOU SO MUCH EVERYONE! The added container within the header was just what I was looking for! I've been wondering about this for some time but couldnt find a definite answer. Also thank-you for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an inner wrapper to your header HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="header_inner"><!-- inner div -->

            <div id="logo">
            </div>
            <div id="nav">
            </div>

        </div><!-- end inner div-->
    </div>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

Then add the same width styling as your container to the wrapper:

```
#header_inner{
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

Then the main content and your header content will align.

Some side notes:

- classes are always better than IDs for styling
- fixed width are generally not a great idea if you're going for a responsive solution

Comment: Thank-you man, and the tips yeah the fixed width, I've been mudling about getting % and px specifications intertwined, getting in a right futz of a situation. So I've changed it all to fixed lengths, but regardless the aligning concept is still useful with respect to having a full width header, feels more 'natural' than using margins to dictate content.

Answer (score 1):

For Fixed Header or Footer you can use

```
.header_class {
  width: 100vw;
  float: left;
  position: fixed !important;
  top: 0px;
  background: url: ('images/img.png') no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
}
```

another better suggestion you can follow facebook header css means upper blue section css (css class name: .fixed_elem, .fixed_always)

Answer (score 0):

I had a little trouble understanding what exactly you were looking to do so I made this example which shows a full page with header and one contained within the middle content area.  The main problem I saw was that when you do things like width:100% it doesnt do 100% it is allowed.. but the full width of the parent element.  You can use width:inherit to get the max width allowed.  Here is the example with a full white header width and one contained using black.  Its all in how you structure the parent child DOM relationship structure

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
<head>  
  <style>body {margin: 0px;background-color: darkgray;}  
         header{background-color: white;height:100px;width:100%;}
         #header{width: inherit;height: 100px;position: fixed;top: 0px;background-image:url("images/bg-header.jpg");opacity: 0.9;background-color: black;}
         #logo {height: 100%;width: 300px;background-color: beige;}
         #container {width: 960px;margin: 0px auto;height: 1000px;background-color:gray;}
         #footer{width: 100%;height: 100px;background-image: url("images/bg-header.jpg");}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <header><div></div></header>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo"></div>
      <div id="nav"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to add a container inside the `#header`. Create a class `.container` that has the properties shared by the `#container` and this container. Also make sure that the container inside the `#header` gets 100% height.

```
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
  opacity: 0.9;
}

#logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: beige;
}

#container {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: gray;
}

#footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="container" class="container">
  <div id="content">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to have a full width 100px header and footer which are fixed to top 0 and bottom 0. but at the same time you want the content to not exactly roll under the header and footer. I hope I understood the question here.

To achieve that obviously give position fixed to header and footer but now to get your content aligned right, you have to give a margin of the height of header and footer ( 100px)

Here is the code snippet... I have added different colors and some filler content to see the difference.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: darkgray;
}
#header,
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
#header {
  top: 0;
}
#footer {
  bottom: 0;
}
#logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: beige;
  float: left;
}
#nav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  background: cyan;
  opacity: 0.5;
  float: right;
}
#container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo">logo</div>
  <div id="nav">nav</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>content
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem many times before, where you want full width images, but they're in containers at a fixed width. At any rate there's a few things you can do here. You can add a container class to every section you want in a container; You put a mini-container in divs you want to break the rules, (this also requires taking said div / #header out of the main #container)

```
#header {  
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
position: fixed;
top: 0px;
background-image: url("images/bg-header.jpg");
opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Than put a div inside of that called content, and set content up like this.

```
.content {  
width: 960px;
margin:0 auto;
display:block;
}
```

So your markup/html should look like

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Home</a></li>
      <li><a>Other</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are more options, but these seem to make sense for this issue.

Hope This Helps,
-Alex